# Javascript: Forloop Difference between i++ and (i+1)

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I was building a javascript for loop and I want to compare the value of an array to the next value in the array.

If both values are not equal, I want to return true, otherwise I want to return false.

In the code below I pass the string "aba", split it and sort it to

```
sortedLetters = ["a", "a", "b"]
```

Yet, when I compare sortedLetters[0] ("a") with sortedLetters[1]

function isIsogram(str){

```
    // split each letter into an array and sort
    sortedLetters = str.split("").sort();

    console.log(sortedLetters[0]); // is "a"
    console.log(sortedLetters[1]); // should be "a"

    // iterate through the array and see if the next array is equal to the current
    // if unequal, return true
    for( i = 0; i < sortedLetters.length; i++ ) {
        if(sortedLetters[i] !== sortedLetters[(i+1)]) return true;
    }
    // for "a" and "a", it should return false

    return false;

};

document.write(isIsogram("aba"));
```

Yet, why does the following if statement work, but the above code does not?

```
if(sortedLetters[i] !== sortedLetters[i++]) return true;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `i++` is using post increment, so the value of the expression `i++` is what the value was in the variable `i` before the increment. This code:

```
if(sortedLetters[i] !== sortedLetters[i++]) return true;
```

does the same thing as:

```
if(sortedLetters[i] !== sortedLetters[i]) return true;
i = i + 1;
```

As `x !== x` always is false for any stable value of `x`, the code does the same thing as:

```
if(false) return true;
i = i + 1;
```

You can use the pre increment version `++i`, but if you increment the variable in the statement, you shouldn't increment it in the loop also:

```
for (i = 0; i < sortedLetters.length; ) {
  if (sortedLetters[i] !== sortedLetters[++i]) return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Quite simply, the indexes are the same in this expression:

```
if(sortedLetters[i] !== sortedLetters[i++]) return true;
```

If the for loop counter is at 3, for example, it will evaluate `sortedLetters[3] !== sortedLetters[3]` *before* incrementing the value.

Using `i++` in your for loop will also double-increment your counter.