# Javascript: Is there a performance difference between i++ and i += 1?

Tags: javascript, increment

There are literally *dozens* of (identical) questions asking about performance differences between i++ and ++i. But what about i++/++i and i += 1? I know it sounds stupid, but it certainly could come in handy in things like search engines or data management `for` loops, where high speed is key. If processing 5,000 sets of data, a 2 millisecond extra delay would add 10 seconds to the proccesing time. Factor in millions of more sets of data, and that few millisecond difference is huge.

**NOTE:** This question has been set as a possible duplicate of [Javascript: Forloop Difference between i++ and (i+1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30974483). It is not, simply because the mentioned question is asking about how to fix a problem in a `for` loop. This question asks about performance differences.

Comment: https://jsperf.com/for-loop-i-vs-i/3

Comment: If you are concerned with that much data you probably shouldn't be using JS to calculate the results....

Comment: @CertainPerformance - why not link to the latest version? https://jsperf.com/for-loop-i-vs-i/8

Comment: Do you really care about performance difference between `var a;` and `var aaa;`?

Answer (score 1):

- `i++` will first calculate the value of `i+1` and then assign it to `i`.
- `i += 1` is the same as `i = i+1`, hence identical as `i++`
- `++i` means the increment happens first, so there's no assignment after (**faster solution**)

Comment: @Mulliganaceous hard to tell. You can compare two `for` loops and profile them. However, with optimization turned on, I don't know if `++i` can be so much faster.

Comment: @Mulliganaceous - you were given a link to a jsperf in another comment - the difference is virtually nothing .. https://jsperf.com/for-loop-i-vs-i/3 . i++, i+=1 12.39 ops per second, ++i 12.28 ops per second - with the +/- 8% variation on all results, there's no discernible difference between the three methods (though, it appears that pre-increment, contrary to popular opinion) is actually marginally **slower** in both firefox and chrome)